# skip first service date only

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I wish to skip first service date for each client only if that service date matches with the clients first ever service.

eg if the client enrolled 1-04-2017

```
client enrollment date     service date

  sam      1-04-2017          1-04-2017
  sam      1-04-2017          1-04-2017
  jon      1-04-2017          1-04-2017

  jon      1-04-2017          1-05-2017 
  sam      1-04-2017          1-05-2017

  jon      1-04-2017          1-07-2017
```

expected result for summary page

```
total clients     total services
  2                      4
```

Expected Result result when I wish to view details

```
client enrollment date     service date

  sam      1-04-2017          1-04-2017
  jon      1-04-2017          1-05-2017 
  sam      1-04-2017          1-05-2017

  jon      1-04-2017          1-07-2017
```

Also you client have one enrollment but multiple services.
How do i skip the first service date on the query considering the fact that the  query will be uploaded to ssrs and the service date will be the variable  s.begindate between @begindate and @enddate .

Comment: The two clients are obvious.  What are the three services?  And what does "offset" mean in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have provided, this is what I am guessing you need.

```
CREATE TABLE T (id int identity, client varchar(10), enrollment_date date, service_date date)

--client enrollment date     service date
INSERT INTO T VALUES 
('sam','1-04-2017','1-04-2017'),
('sam','1-04-2017','1-04-2017'),
('jon','1-04-2017','1-04-2017'),
('jon','1-04-2017','1-05-2017'),
('sam','1-04-2017','1-05-2017'),
('jon','1-04-2017','1-07-2017')

DECLARE @StartDate date = '1-04-2017', @EndDate date = '1-07-2017'

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT client) AS total_clients, COUNT(1)-COUNT(DISTINCT client) AS total_services
FROM T 
WHERE service_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

SELECT DISTINCT T.* 
FROM T T JOIN (SELECT client, MIN(id) AS enroll_id FROM T GROUP BY client) E
ON T.client = E.client
AND T.id <> E.enroll_id
WHERE service_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
ORDER BY 2, 3

DROP TABLE T
```

These are the new result I get from this.

```
total_clients total_services
------------- --------------
2             4

id          client     enrollment_date service_date
----------- ---------- --------------- ------------
4           jon        2017-01-04      2017-01-05
6           jon        2017-01-04      2017-01-07
2           sam        2017-01-04      2017-01-04
5           sam        2017-01-04      2017-01-05
```

This just subtracts the distinct count of clients from the overall count to offset the enrollment event.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: This is a really reasonable interpretation.  It would be nice of the OP clarified that this is what he really wants.

Comment: Yes, some additional details would be nice. I started to code up something like what you posted, but then the fact that many of the service dates matched the enrollment dates threw me. I like the idea of a solution being this easy, but something always comes along... :)

Comment: Hi all sorry for not giving as much detail a possible. I have updated the question to include more details.

Comment: @HenryAmadi Do your dates actually have a time with them in the database? You need something that could differentiate the enroll date from the service date. Or, are they all just a data without a time?

Comment: oh no it has 12:00 am attached to all.

Comment: Okay, then how about a key on the table? Something that will uniquely identify each row. Do you have one that perhaps you just haven't shown us in your question?

Comment: Oh yeah, each service has a unique key and enrollment has only one for each client but multiple services tied to each enrollment,

Comment: I have updated my answer to mock a unique key. I am hoping you can adapt this to what you need. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you would seem to want a simple `where` clause using a window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(enrollment_date) over (partition by client) as first_enrollment_date
      from t
     ) t
where first_enrollment_date > service_date;
```

However, this would leave only two services, so it is unclear what you really want.